# iOS: Setting multiple colors of table row

Tags: uitableview, ios4, appcelerator-mobile

Is it possible to set two colors or transparency of the portion of the cell? something like this [image](http://i49.tinypic.com/22c3du.jpg) where you can see both dark green and light green?

I am looking for both native and Titanium Appcelerator based solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to add and position a CALayer (as a sublayer) onto the existing UITableViewCell's layer and set the colours of the cell's layer and your new sublayer to your requirements.
Coding properties on your UITableViewCell.m file for convenience could also be helpful.

A useful link if you are unfamiliar with CALayers http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/introduction-to-calayers-tutorial